# change the output style of sass with web essentials

Tags: sass, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

Is there a way to change the output file style of a scss processed by Web-Essentials in visual-studio 2013 ?

I want to change the output style to one of the sass output style like :
`:compact`, `:nested`, `:compressed`, `:nested`

I found in the options how to specify the output directory, the "with source map files", but no idea how to change the compilation style type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outputstyle option was not implemented in Web Essentials.

After having installed the `Visual Studio 2013 update 2`, I was able to update to `Web Essentials 2013 For VS2013 Update 2` and this new version has an option to set the Output Style. All 4 styles are available (nested, expanded, compact, compressed)

Answer (score 0):

Just been looking into this myself.

The setting you are looking for is `"OutputStyle": "Expanded",` with `Expanded` being the default.

Unfortunately the precompiler used by Web Essentials (libsass) currently only supports `nested` and `compressed`; I was hoping for `compact`.

[Source](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/233)

Comment: update your `VS` and `WE` version to have this option available (see answer above)